# Using Pascal's formula to derive another formula

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Use Pascal’s formula repeatedly to derive a formula for $\dbinom{n+3}{r}$ in terms of values of $\dbinom{n}{k}$ with $k \leq r.$ (Assume $n$ and $r$ are integers with $n\geq r \geq 3).$

I have a idea about this question but I don't know how to convert $r$ to $k$.

Comment: You can produce $\leq$ and $\geq$ by typing, respectively, \leq and \geq when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{n+3}r&=\binom{n+2}{r-1}+\binom{n+2}r\\\\
&=\left(\binom{n+1}{r-2}+\binom{n+1}{r-1}\right)+\left(\binom{n+1}{r-1}+\binom{n+1}r\right)\\\\
&=\ldots
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Ok but how I will insert a "k" in this terms?

Comment: @Vinicius: You won’t. The problem isn’t asking for an answer that uses the letter $k$; it’s asking for an answer that expresses $\binom{n+3}r$ in terms of binomial coefficients whose upper numbers are all $n$ and whose lower numbers are at most $r$.